# Adding a tab to the "Add Reference" dialog in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, dialog, add-in

Been working on a personal add-in for VS 2008 and have been researching automation and control. I see there are lots of examples for adding a .dll reference to the registry so they show in the ".NET" tab in the Add Reference dialog.

What I would like to do, however, is add a new tab to the reference dialog with some functionality therein. Is it possible to do this? I can't seem to find any documentation for modifying the Add Reference dialog.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More interesting info can now be found in the MSDN forums. I have a bit more success, but am not totally done yet. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/ddb0f935-b8ac-400d-9e3d-64d74be85031/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about extending the existing dialog, but you might consider creating your own.  Here is [a blog post](http://devlicio.us/blogs/tuna_toksoz/archive/2009/06/18/vs-addin-fast-add-reference-dialog-no-more-coffee-break.aspx) where someone created a new dialog in order to have a faster load time.  You might be able to start with that code and modify as needed.